# custom module positions per user in dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have experience with drupal but not DNN. 
I am interested in seeing if DNN has a module or the ability to have a page that each individual user with an account on my dnn site can arrange the modules on their home page. Sort of like a widget system where users can drag modules around or hide them if they choose. However, as the admin, i'd like to limit which modules they can have access to and move.

In drupal, there is a module called "homebox" that allows for this.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the answer is not out of the box.

That said it would be possible to develop something and there may be something available at store.dnnsoftware.com that would do this for you.

not a lot of help but it may save you some time looking for stuff hat is not there.